Python Requests module performance after 3.11.4
I am having issues with the requests module with web requests taking significantly longer in Python versions after 3.11.4. Done a bunch of Google searching and can't find anything directly related to this.
Here's some code to test. The behavior of this code is consistent across many computers in my organization. All these tests are run on Windows 10 and the results are all from the same computer with Python versions 3.11.4, 3.11.5, and 3.12.3. I have virtual environments created with venv for each those versions.
The performance decrease happens when we upgrade from 3.11.4 to anything newer. Performance comes back when we uninstall anything newer and re-install 3.11.4.
Code I'm running:
import requests
import datetime

starttime = datetime.datetime.now()

for i in range(10):
    response = requests.get(f"https://google.com?param={i}")
    data = response.text

endtime = datetime.datetime.now()

print(f"requests test elapsed - {(endtime - starttime).total_seconds()}s")

Average time to completion of the above code over 10 iterations.

Python 3.11.4: 2.2s
Python 3.11.5: 19s
Python 3.12.3: 18s

Anyone have any idea what might be happening here? FYI, this also happens with the httpx module but not with the urllib module. urllib performance is consistent across versions while the httpx module performance degrades after 3.11.4 too.

hm, I only have python 3.11.4 and 3.11.8 at hand right now, but they both take about 2s

Also not able to reproduce with the version I have on hand (3.10 and 3.12.3), both taking about 6s for me.
This question made me think of retrospective on requests, written by one of the original authors of the library. They point out many of the (nearly unfixable) issues with requests, I could imagine this being related one way or another - though I doubt it'll help you resolve your issue. Glad to see you're already aware of alternative libraries.

Could you share some profiling results, so we can help hunt down the issue? You can use python's builtin profiler: import cProfile; cProfile.run("""your code here"""). Getting both fast + slow versions to compare would be great, but at least the slow one would be something to go off of.

Sorry for asking, you sure have same version of requests library?

Thanks for the info and suggestions, especially the profiling. I had profiled a more complicated version and the results weren't as clear.
When I profiled this code, the main bottleneck was this section:
      20   16.272    0.814   16.272    0.814 {method 'load_verify_locations' of '_ssl._SSLContext' objects}

This led me to this page which seems to make it clear that this is an openSSL issue
In my case, I'm able to update our code to utilize sessions as suggested in the above page. While the speed isn't quite as fast as the openSSL version included in Python 3.11.4, it's acceptable for my purposes.
Here's the new code:
import requests
import datetime

starttime = datetime.datetime.now()

session = requests.Session()

for i in range(10):
    response = session.get(f"https://google.com?param={i}")
    data = response.text

session.close()

endtime = datetime.datetime.now()

print(f"requests test elapsed - {(endtime - starttime).total_seconds()}s")

With this code, the results are:

Python 3.11.4 - 3.1s
Python 3.12.3 - 4.7s

Note that actual time is dependant on speed of connection. The important part is how much faster I'm getting results on Python 3.12.3 compared to not using sessions.
